# Indenting listview item with icon in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I want to create list view with indented icon and I came across that:

[image]

There is a solution, but it's non-dotnet and I was wondering how I could achieve this with C#?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the solution written in.. perhaps you could convert the source to .NET also that looks kind of sloppy why not use a `TreeView` instead..? just my visual observation

Comment: @DJKRAZE I don't think TreeViews can be multi-column. OP is trying to do something like Visual Studio's TreeListViews (visible in "pending changes" windows).

Comment: This doesn't look like it has multi-columns

Comment: @KingKing it certainly has at least one column. Name.

Comment: @Gusdor could you show me any control which doesn't seem to have 1 column? even a `TextBox` has at least 1 column.

Answer (score 2):

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.indentcount%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Use the `IndentCount` property of the `ListViewItem`s.

However see the remark there:

> The IndentCount property can be used only when the View property of
>   the containing ListView is set to Details, and the SmallImageList
>   property of the ListView is set.

The example there works easily.